# Trying to place a banner style add to scroll with content

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, admob

I'm new to AdMob and I have an ionic ios app where I want to have banners appear within the content. But the samples I see only allow you to have it to display staticly at the bottom of all the content.

If anyone has a similar setup, can you point me to how to config this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

standard 320x50 banners appear on top or at the bottom of the screen. Ads displaying within the content are called "native ads". native is a separate ad format that usually offers several "subformats/placements" like content stream, newsfeed;, native video etc. 
you can also check the info from [admob documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native) 
i'd also add that native ads look best in utility apps (if you have a game, interstitials and video are likely to bring more revenue).
also if you have a big audience and want to keep balance between earning on ads and user retention - native ads is a good option, but as it's relatively new format i'd recommend to use mediator - to have access to multiple networks that support native ads (applovin, flurry, facebook, stratapp, inmobi, mopub, etc)

Comment: Thanks, kawabungajohn